# При отправке на сервер стоящий на Bottle py русских символов получаю битую кодировку

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

Отправляю таким запросом `requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:80/bolezn',headers={'Content-Type':'utf8'},data={'simptomes':[u'Вялость',u'Боль']})`, получаю в ответе `['Ð\x92Ñ\x8fÐ»Ð¾Ñ\x81Ñ\x82Ñ\x8c', 'Ð\x91Ð¾Ð»Ñ\x8c']`, как это перекодировать или что с этим делать?

```py
#Сам код со стороны сервера
@post('/bolezn')
def bolezn():
    simptomes = request.forms.getall('simptomes')
    print(simptomes)
```

Comment: А скрипт, из которого отправляете запрос, сам точно в кодировке `UTF-8` в файл записан? Вообще под какой ОС обе сообщающихся стороны сидят и на какой версии питона? А то меня вот это `u'Вялость'` смущает, префикс `u` нужен был только в старом питоне 2.x, для которого кодировка `UTF-8` ещё не родная. И вообще может вы из-под Windows обращаетесь и файл у вас в кодировке `cp1251`. Всё может быть.

Comment: Это кодировка UTF-8 выведенная в ASCII. `'Ð\x92Ñ\x8fÐ»Ð¾Ñ\x81Ñ\x82Ñ\x8c'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf8')` -> `Вялость`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, префикс `u` я использовал чисто для проверки, вдруг так сработает и не заметил что не убрал его отсюда, на обоих сторонах Windows и на обоих py 3.9.6
@GrAnd, Благодарю, помогло